# jquery form plugin & programmatic submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

There are similar questions at SO, but none that seem to address this.

Below is a very simplified variant of my situation. Drupal/PHP site -- I have a form w/ submit button that I am using jquery.form plugin to ajax-ly submit. It works fine if I use the submit (#submit) button.

Now, I want to programmatically fire that button using another button (#submit2) outside of the form. I can do that using jquery click() function, but the content coming back isn't going to the ajax target as I would expect.

I do not have much freedom to re-organize this code, else i would.

(Note I tried to make this code easy for you to run by src-ing jquery and the form plugin from my website.)

Ideas? Thanks!

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['submit'] == 'Submit') {
    print 'ajax returns ... ' . $_REQUEST['text']; 
    exit; 
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://enjoy3d.com/scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://enjoy3d.com/scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#form').ajaxForm( { target: $('#span') } );
            $('#submit2').click( function() { $('#submit').click(); } );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id='span'>target span</span>
    <form method='post' id='form'>
        <input type='text' name='text' size='50' />
        <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
    </form>
    <input type='submit' id='submit2' name='submit2' value='Submit Too?' />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve a similar situation to yours. If the only objective of simulating a click on submit1 is to submit the form, you might try:

```
$('#submit2').click(function() {
    $('#form').trigger('submit');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to `return false` immediately after triggering the form submit button from the non-form submit button click event code. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#form').ajaxForm({ target: $('#span') });
    $('#submit2').click(function() { $('#submit').click(); return false; });
  });
</script>
```

It works for me. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: really, it worked for you?  Didn't make any difference when I tried your suggestion. Clicking submit2 caused the page to reload showing only the ajax result content (input field goes away)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving a name to the form, and instead of

```
$('#submit2').click( function() { $('#submit').click(); } );
```

doing

```
$('#submit2').click( function() { document.myForm.submit(); } );
```

That should do the same thing as having the submit button clicked if the form has been ajaxified.

Comment: the jquery.form plugin binds functionality to the submit button's click event, so submitting the form directly doesn't work